# How do capacitors and inductors behave while they are charging in a circuit with a DC source?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

In an RC circuit the fully charged capacitors behave like an open circuit, the inductors, in one of type RL, are taken as short circuits.

Comment: Please draw a circuit diagram so that the reader can understand what you're asking,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Ideal) capacitors *always* 'behave' as

$$i_C = C \frac{dv_C}{dt}$$

That is, the current through a capacitor is *always* proportional to the time rate of change of the voltage across the capacitor.

So, when the voltage across a capacitor is *constant*, the current through the capacitor is *zero* (like an open circuit).  Otherwise, the current through the capacitor is *not* zero.

Similarly, (ideal) inductors *always* behave has

$$v_L = L \frac{di_L}{dt}$$

That is, the voltage across an inductor is *always* proportional to the time rate of change of the current through the inductor.

So, when the current through an inductor is *constant*, the voltage across the inductor is *zero* (like a short circuit).  Otherwise, the voltage across the inductor is *not* zero.